# Carregar arquivo txt através de uma lista c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

Faço uma consulta no banco e coloco em uma lista, depois varro cada item da lista através do `foreach` para consultar outras tabelas conforme o Id de cada linha percorrida. Se encontrado, gostaria de carregar um arquivo `txt` para cada linha consultada, saltando dentro do arquivo `txt`.

EX:

- maria  rua 3 cidade Sao paulo
- sidnei rua 3 cidade Campinas

O que não consigo fazer é delimitar o comprimento total da linha pois tem que ser fixa. Estou fazendo em C# com `StringBuilder`:
    Ex:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    foreach (var item in registros) 
    { 
        string testeID = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());         
        string testecodigo = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["CODIGO"].Value.ToString());
    }


  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in registros)
            {
                 areaNaoConstaRecebe = " ";
                folhaRecebe = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["FOLHA"].Value.ToString());
                folhaRecebe = folhaRecebe.PadRight(5, ' ');
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}",
                 idRegistro = "1",
                 numeroControle = "          ",
                 folhaRecebe ="uuuuu",
```

A primeira consulta salva uma linha da lista, a segunda consulta pode ter 5 linhas e deverão ser populada. Depois a
 terceira por ter 2 linha e devera ser gravado, ai ele colta a lista principal e faz novamente a consulta e assim por diante.
O tamanho seria de 832 colunas.

Comment: Mostre o que fez. E diga onde está tendo dificuldade.

Comment: este é o comando que uso para gravar..Environment.NewLine);
                "File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Clientes_Formatado.txt", sb.ToString())"

Comment: Você quer dizer q cada vez q vc faz uma consulta ele limpar o arquivo e começa de novo? Se não, qual seria o problema q está tendo, não entendi bem.

Comment: O problema é que ao gravar a primeira linha, é gravado tambem a segunda na mesma linha.Fica gravado uma sequencia com os dados do primeiro e do segundo,

Answer (score 1):

Acrescente um `AppendLine` no fim

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}",
                     idRegistro = "1",
                     numeroControle = "          ",
                     folhaRecebe ="uuuuu")
  .AppendLine();
```

Comment: Que bom Bruno... deu certíssimo. Muito obrigado pela dica....

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade Agradeça votando e aceitando a resposta.